Looking for FreeMarker template with name [error_en.ftlh] | TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("error_en.ftlh"): Not found
See this :
enter image description here
Supposed to get this dashboard instead getting
enter image description here
I have configured a eureka server with all the things that are required but still I am not able to see the eureka dashboard instead I am getting the white label error and in the console
2024-06-18T11:44:19.065+05:30 DEBUG 22864 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] freemarker.cache                         : TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("error_en.ftlh"): Not found 2024-06-18T11:44:19.065+05:30 DEBUG 22864 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.ui.freemarker.SpringTemplateLoader   : Looking for FreeMarker template with name [error.ftlh]
I am trying to solve the error but I am not able to. I a expected to get the eureka dashboard
so my code are
pom.xml

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>eureka-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


application.properties

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eureka?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin

#eureka.server.enable-self-preservation=false

spring.freemarker.template-loader-path= classpath:/templates/
#spring.thymeleaf.enabled = false


#spring.freemarker.prefer-file-system-access= false
logging.level.root=DEBUG
server.port=8761

eureka.client.register-with-eureka = false
eureka.client.fetch-registry = false


eureka.client.registerWithEureka = false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry = false
#eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761

EurekaMain.java

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaMain.class);
        System.out.println("Eureka service running in 8761 ...");
    }
}

and in the resource folder I have only application.properties
error trace in terminal
2024-06-18T12:54:18.924+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state LivenessState changed to CORRECT
2024-06-18T12:54:18.928+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC
Eureka service running in 8761 ...
2024-06-18T12:55:03.665+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.a.c.a.jaspic.AuthConfigFactoryImpl     : Loading persistent provider registrations from [C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.8761.12312975891682176073\conf\jaspic-providers.xml]
2024-06-18T12:55:03.668+05:30  INFO 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-06-18T12:55:03.668+05:30  INFO 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-06-18T12:55:03.668+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2024-06-18T12:55:03.668+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
2024-06-18T12:55:03.668+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected FixedThemeResolver
2024-06-18T12:55:03.669+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@585a7512
2024-06-18T12:55:03.670+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@3223785f
2024-06-18T12:55:03.670+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2024-06-18T12:55:03.670+05:30  INFO 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2024-06-18T12:55:03.694+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/", parameters={}
2024-06-18T12:55:03.706+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2024-06-18T12:55:03.708+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2024-06-18T12:55:03.712+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource .]
2024-06-18T12:55:03.713+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2024-06-18T12:55:03.722+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2024-06-18T12:55:03.727+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2024-06-18T12:55:03.760+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] freemarker.cache                         : Couldn't find template in cache for "error.ftlh"("en_US", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
2024-06-18T12:55:03.760+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.ui.freemarker.SpringTemplateLoader   : Looking for FreeMarker template with name [error_en_US.ftlh]
2024-06-18T12:55:03.761+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] freemarker.cache                         : TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("error_en_US.ftlh"): Not found
2024-06-18T12:55:03.763+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.ui.freemarker.SpringTemplateLoader   : Looking for FreeMarker template with name [error_en.ftlh]
2024-06-18T12:55:03.763+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] freemarker.cache                         : TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("error_en.ftlh"): Not found
2024-06-18T12:55:03.763+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.ui.freemarker.SpringTemplateLoader   : Looking for FreeMarker template with name [error.ftlh]
2024-06-18T12:55:03.764+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] freemarker.cache                         : TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("error.ftlh"): Not found
2024-06-18T12:55:03.766+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2024-06-18T12:55:03.773+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
2024-06-18T12:55:10.832+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-3] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header

java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1293) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1181) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:348) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2024-06-18T12:55:10.833+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header

java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1293) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1181) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:348) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2024-06-18T12:55:10.833+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-3] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error state [CLOSE_CONNECTION_NOW] reported while processing request

java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1293) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1181) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:348) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2024-06-18T12:55:10.834+05:30 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error state [CLOSE_CONNECTION_NOW] reported while processing request

java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1293) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1181) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:348) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

